# Bootloop when trying to try out elementary os from bootable usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb-drive, startup

I'm trying to try out elementary os from a bootable usb, but every time I hit the 'try elementary os' button, the pc shuts down and when I boot it again, I  receive the exact same screen and the same outcome when trying to try out.
I have more than once used the try out function before on multiple devices and it always worked like a charm, I really have no clue what's different this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run Linux in single mode and get into the system to remove the splash screen from the /etc/default/grub and then you will be able to see what is going on. The splash screen is nice but nonsense, because when there is an issue during the start of the system users are unable to see what is wrong. If you want to do that, let me know and I will provide a tutorial. This is rather not for the beginner. One more time Elementary OS developers made me sure they have no idea what Linux was invented for. It should work, not look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Single user mode in Ubuntu/Elementary OS

Ubuntu/Elementary OS will drop you into single user mode automatically if it cannot boot normally. To manually enter single user mode, use the following instructions:

From GRUB, press 'e' to edit your boot entry (the Ubuntu entry).

Look for the line that starts with linux, then look for ro

Add single after ro, ensuring there is a space before and after single

Press Ctrl + X to reboot with these settings and enter single user mode

Answer (score 0):

Open /etc/default/grub in a text editor of your choice and remove quiet splash.

Example:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Press insert button on your keyboard.

Remove mentioned words quiet splash

Press Esc button on your keyboard.

Type :x

Type one by one commands below:

```
sudo update-grub 

sudo reboot
```

Then remove single using above tutorial and then one more time sudo reboot.

Check errors showing on screen.